# How can I trace ASP.Net JIT Compilation? Its very slow

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, precompile

How can I trace the JIT compilation of an application? We have a small asp.net application that is part of a larger website (classic asp for the rest of the code) so it's not accessed very frequently and is (likely) recompiling after a timeout or app pool recycle. The recompilation is taking up to 2 minutes!!

Is there a tracing tool or counters in perfmon that can help me trace what exactly is going on?

I was going to try and precompile but I think timeouts and app pool recycles will render that useless. (or is that a bad assumption?)

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you truly believe that the problem is Jit, you can use .NET Performance Counters. Open the "Performance" Management Console (it varies by operating system) and click the +, then add the `.NET CLR Jit` counter:

[image: Jit Performance Counter]

This will allow you to get some simple metrics about Jit, how much time is being spent in it, etc.

Now, I don't think the problem is entirely on "Jit". It might be ASP.NET compiling your application into `Temporary ASP.NET Files`, it might be Strong Name signature checking, etc. I would consider many other things besides the CLR Jit.

Jit specifically is when IL code is compiled into native code by the runtime, or finds it in NGEN. Your whole application doesn't get JITed all at once - each method is JITed on a case by case basis.

I think your best shot is to also look at the Compilations Total counter under the `ASP.NET Applications` object, and try pre-compiling your website.

Comment: Looks like you're right. % Time in Jit maxed at 17 but didnt go above 0 until almost a minute after I clicked the link to that particular application. Are there any counters to track the processes prior to Jit?

Comment: Ooh...second question too... is there a way to "reset" everything? I am waiting an hour between tests cause a simple app pool recycle isn't producing the 1.5 minute intial load... just when I wait for a while before going to that link again. Thx!

Comment: Shawn, I am working on Q1. For Q2, try stopping IIS, and deleting everything in `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\FrameworkXX\vZZZZZZ\Temporary ASP.NET Files` Where XX is either nothing or 64 if your worker process is 64-bit; and where ZZZZZ is the version of the .NET Framework of the AppPool. For example, if my App Pool is 32-bit and on .NET Framework 4, it would be `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`. Then start IIS back up.

Comment: Shawn, when your application is loading, do you see a process called `vbc.exe` running in the task manager? (Make sure you are showing processes for all users).

Comment: Others dev's on that machine so i couldnt stop IIS but I did stop the app pool my app is in and was able to remove the temp files there. Thx for that and thx for taking the time to help with the other part!

Comment: Shawn - is your application compiled at all (Does your code get compiled into a bin)? Is it a Web Application or Web Site? I'm leaning toward the problem being dynamic compilation. Have you tried using pre-compilation as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976.aspx ?

Comment: When I delete the temp files and retry, it doesn't take the full 1.5 min to run on the initial click...its only about 20 sec.. I guess that means the compilation part is 20 sec leaving the other minute to still try and identify.

Comment: @vcsjones let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1707/discussion-between-shawn-dube-and-vcsjones)

Comment: Just to round this out. Im going to trial dotTrace as @vcsjones suggested. If I figure out the bottleneck, i'll try and come back and post the details here.